# PHP: Regex to transform only phone number to html A-tag in text

Tags: php, regex

I want to transform all phone number in the following text to HTML A tag:

```
My phone number is 06 06 06 06 06.

But this one can write +33 606 06 06 06.

My facebook profile is https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100060606060606.
```

The feature should render the text as follow:

```
My phone number is <a href="tel:06 06 06 06 06">06 06 06 06 06</a>.

But this one can write <a href="tel:+33 606 06 06 06">+33 606 06 06 06</a>.

My facebook profile is https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100060606060606.
```

I trying to use `preg_replace` with the REGEX `#(?:(?:\+|00)33|0)\s*[1-9](?:[\s.-]*\d{2}){4}#`

However, this regex also capture number in the facebook link.

How can construct my regex to avoid capture number in facebook link or maybe another solution to do my task in PHP ?

Comment: Is there always a space before the number?

Comment: If there is (or at start) [preceed  the pattern with `(?<!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/41jB4H/1) further you could exclude links using [`\bhttps?:\S+(*SKIP)(*F)|what I want...`](https://regex101.com/r/GVOeMC/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add digit boundaries in places where they are relevant:

```php
(?:(?:\+|(?<!\d)00)33|(?<!\d)0)\s*[1-9](?:[\s.-]*\d{2}){4}(?!\d)
//       ^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^                             ^^^^^^
```

Here, `(?<!\d)` is a left-hand digit boundary and `(?!\d)` is a right-hand digit boundary. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bkvWjN/1).

Note there is no digit boundary pattern before the `\+` part, since `+` is already a non-digit char.

Another pattern with the similar logic can be written with word and non-word boundaries:

```php
(?:(?:\B\+|\b00)33|\b0)\s*[1-9](?:[\s.-]*\d{2}){4}\b
//    ^^   ^^      ^^                             ^^
```

Here, `\B` is placed before `\+` to match it at the start of string or when it is immediately preceded with any other non-word char. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bkvWjN/2). Note it is more restrictive than the first regex.